# node.js - finding path of require()ing module

Tags: javascript, node.js

trying to find the proper way to determine the path of the module require()ing mine given the following requirements:

- must be strict mode compliant
- cannot make any assumptions about program args (i.e. process.argv)
- must work when required from multiple modules in arbitrary locations a single execution (i.e. my module is cached)

I ended up getting this to work by patching Module._load() and capturing the callers path in a closure as shown here: [github](https://github.com/bodenr/expose/blob/master/index.js)

However this doesn't feel right -- I must be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Patching `module._load` is the best way I think. You can only get the first module who called your module by `module.parent.filename`. And the whole `children` and `parent` properties of module are only true for the first time load. According to the [source code](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/module.js#L283), if it's cached you can't rely on anything. You can try remove yourself from the cache(`delete require.cache[__filename]`;) which then everytime your module is required, you get the right parent, but that will increase your load time.